# How to get the parent(/parent/parent/..etc) controller from inside a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

I have 3 directives, which structure might look something like this:

```
<my-component>
    <my-items>
        <my-item="item" ng-repeat="item in MyItems.items">
            {{ item.name }}
            <!-- item.children -->
            <my-items>
                <my-item="item" ng-repeat="item in MyItems.items" />
            </my-items>
        </my-item>
    <my-items>
</my-component>
```

where the depth of `my-items` can be infinite (in theory).

Now I want to have the `my-component` hold the (ONE!) item that the user selects and add a conditional selected class, so in (~pseudo) code which will look something like this:

```
<my-item="item" ng-click="myComponent.selected = item"
                ng-class="{ selected: myComponent.selected == item }" />
```

How can I know in here what the selected item is of the `my-component`?

I have tried to do this in myItems directive:

```
// itemsComponentController is the controller of my-component
require: "^^itemsComponentController";
```

But angular here throws the error it cannot find such a controller. What am I doing wrong here with the `require`? Does it not find controllers that are not its direct parents?

I have it working on emitting the 'item-selected' event, which is handled in the controller by doing the `scope.$on("item-selected")`, but then I still cannot know the `myComponent.selected` in `<my-item>`

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc0rwz8n/5/) for the (minimalistic?) typescript version of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue!

I don't have to require the controller's name, but instead require the directive's name. Then the controller of that directive will be passed as variable in the `link` function:

```
// Require the name of the (parent) directive instead of its controller name
require: "^^myComponent";
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
    // ctrl is the controller of <my-component>
    // so now I can do ctrl.itemSelected()
}
```

[The working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc0rwz8n/7/)